# Is there a "requester pays" attribute for S3 Buckets being created with CloudFormation Templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a CloudFormation Template (CFT) for a S3 Bucket that needs to be "PublicRead" and that also has "Requester Pays" turned on.

I have looked at the documentation for S3 Bucket CFTs: [AWS::S3::Bucket - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-accesscontrol)

Also I have looked at the documentation for "Requester Pays", but it fails to mention anything about CFTs.  It only references enabling it through the console and with the REST API:
[Requester Pays Buckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html)

Right now we are trying to get all our infrastructure into infrastructure as code, but this is a somewhat large blocker for that.  I have heard that other people have had trouble with CFTs not supporting some features from AWS services, but usually those are for unpopular/newer services.  I would think that CFT would support all the options that S3 has for buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The CloudFormation [AWS::S3::Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html) resources does not support Requester Pays.

The enable it, you would need to make an API call such as [`put_bucket_request_payment()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_request_payment):

> Sets the request payment configuration for a bucket. By default, the bucket owner pays for downloads from the bucket. This configuration parameter enables the bucket owner (only) to specify that the person requesting the download will be charged for the download.

```py
response = client.put_bucket_request_payment(
    Bucket='string',
    RequestPaymentConfiguration={
        'Payer': 'Requester'|'BucketOwner'
    }
)
```

This could be done by adding an **AWS Lambda custom resource** to the CloudFormation template, or by using the AWS CLI from an Amazon EC2 instance that is created as part of the stack.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew that this problem with CloudFormation exists, but I had yet to run into this problem.  I like the suggestion of using a Lambda function to automatically attach requester pays to buckets.